# How can we put menus at the to to screens?

Tags: android, menu

I want to put 5 images side by side at top of screen.
When i click one image i want to display list of another images horizontally
can any one suggest me?

Comment: You haven't accepted a single answer and you ask another one, which is simple "please, solve my problem for me, I haven't even try". Do you really think people is going to help you?

Comment: Learn how Android lets you layout images, and then layout images that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can create 2 nested horizontal LinearLayouts in layout XML file, with second being empty, but having ID, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="0px"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="0px"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton3" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="0px"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton4" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="0px"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

Then in Java code you can add second row of images dynamically, via first row buttons onClickListeners, like so (example only adds 1 image to the second row):

```
firstButtonInFirstLine = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    firstButtonInFirstLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LinearLayout secondLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(MainAct.this);
            btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.misc);
            secondLinearLayout.addView(btn);
        }
    });
```

You can achieve same thing with clickable ImageView elements.